# Error awaiting DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector) with System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime referenced

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await, desktop-application, win-universal-app

I'm writing code in a desktop application that discovers and connects to devices with Wi-Fi Direct for Windows 10. I've followed the [instructions](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jeffreyr/using-the-windows-runtime-from-a-non-metro-application) on how to call Windows Runtime API from non-WinRT environment, everything is fine on VS 2013 except the following lines and I move them in a console application targeting .NET Framework 4.5:

```
using System;

using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect;

static void Main()
{
    DoSomethingAsync().Wait();
}

static async void DoSomethingAsync()
{
    var selector = WiFiDirectDevice.GetDeviceSelector(WiFiDirectDeviceSelectorType.DeviceInterface);
    foreach (var info in await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector)) // <-- error
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And the error is still

> 'await' requires that the type
>   '`Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformationCollection>`'
>   have a suitable GetAwaiter method. Are you missing a using directive
>   for 'System'?

with following library references: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COTrA.png)

- System.Runtime, C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll
- System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime, C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
- Windows.Devices, C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\Windows.Devices.winmd
- Windows.Foundation, C:\Windows\System32\WinMetadata\Windows.Foundation.winmd

I'm sure `selector` could be retrieved correctly (something like

```
System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:="{439B20AF-8955-405B-99F0-A62AF0C68D43}" 
AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True
```

), then I assume the hack is still valid for desktop applications on Windows 10.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Even after resolving the dependencies of what you're doing, it won't work. `Main` can't be marked with the async modifier.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, thank you for the comment and sorry I made the mistake to put my lines in the Main method.

Comment: It's alright. Was just pointing you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 6):

Thank you very much, @Yuval Itzchakov, @vidalsasoon

It turns out I was mislead by the path where `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` locates. In `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5` the library is actually of .NET Framework 4.0, in which no such extension methods(`GetWaiter`, `AsTask`...) are defined. However, it looks like the folder is the default location when you're referencing .NET Framework assemblies in VS.

Then I'm referencing

- `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`, of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`
- `Windows`, of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd`

and now it's working.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding "AsTask()" to the IAsyncOperation and work around the issue that Yuval mentioned.

```
static void Main()
{
    var selector = WiFiDirectDevice.GetDeviceSelector();

    var findAllDevicesTask = DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync().AsTask();

    Task.WaitAll(findAllDevicesTask);

    for (var info in findAllDevicesTask.Result)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying and sure I need to use `AsTask()` in my code, though it didn't work without changeing the reference. Please check my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried a million different ways which all resulted in some kind of deadlock. This is the only method which worked!